# How to remove decimal values?

Tags: magento-1.9

Iam getting decimal points [image: in this way] please help me in removing those decimal points.

Comment: You should add the code that generates the slider. This is not a standard magento functionality.

Comment: Either contact the authors of the extension or, if it is a free, open source, extension, add the code of the template and the block classes to your post.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.

Comment: What module are you using? If it is older version of the Improved Navigation, just upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this file from core to local:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php
```

The find line 60 and change the following lines from:

```
  $fromPrice  = $store->formatPrice(($value-1)*$range);
    $toPrice    = $store->formatPrice($value*$range);
```

to

```
  $fromPrice  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol().($value-1)*$range;
    $toPrice    = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol().($value*$range);
```

This will remove the decimals and makes sure it keeps the currency symbol using this:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol()
```

See:http://way2discuss.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-remove-price-decimal-in-magento.html

Comment: thankyou for this but this removed decimals from product pricing but not from that slider section as shown in above image actually it is a extension and I searched that extensions files and cannot found any option to change that.